# php5-fpm status page is blank for when using nginx 1.10.3 but works with 1.4.6

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I just run into some issue while trying to hook some nodes to datadog for monitoring.

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.5 LTS. I added a `nginx ppa:nginx/stable` so I got nginx 1.10.3 installed.

my nginx configuration /etc/nginx/sites-available/check.conf

```
server {

      listen         80 ;
      server_name    localhost;

      root /usr/share/nginx/html/vhosts/elbcheck/htdocs;
      index index.php;
      access_log off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                              try_files $uri =404;
                              fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                              fastcgi_index index.php;
                              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                              include fastcgi_params;
    }


    location / {
                              try_files $uri =404;
                  }

    location /nginx_status {

            stub_status on;
             access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
     }

    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

}
```

The configuration above works with nginx 1.4.6 but blank in nginx 1.10.3. Is there anything step I am missing aside uncommenting pm.status_path and ping.path ?

Thanks

Comment: What does nginx `error.log` show?

Comment: No error nothing at all. Sorry for the late revert

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP-FPM status is empty](https://serverfault.com/questions/896469/php-fpm-status-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401702/php-fpm-status-page-is-blank-after-nginx-update-from-1-2-1-to-1-9-2/33449162#33449162)

I have added the following lines and it's was good again

```
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

So full configuration would be

```
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

}
```