# PHP-FPM status is empty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04

I set up `pm.status_path = /status` option:

```
ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf | egrep 'listen|status'
listen = /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
pm.status_path = /status
```

Socket is correct (and sites work):

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo ls -la /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Feb  9 07:58 /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
```

But I can't receive this status page:

```
ubuntu:~$ SCRIPT_NAME=/status SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status \
> REQUEST_METHOD=GET sudo cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Or using nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /status {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

`curl http://localhost/status` is empty, status code is 200.
`curl http://localhost/something` returns error 404 as expected.

What should I do to solve this situation? What to check?

Comment: Is it also empty if you access `/status?full` ?

Comment: @pkhamre yes, it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the PHP-FPM status page to work properly under nginx, the following parameters must all be set:

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME       /status;   # see notes below
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   "";        # see notes below
```

`REQUEST_METHOD` and `QUERY_STRING` are set by `include fastcgi_params`. If you're using this configuration file, you don't need to set these again.

The value of `SCRIPT_NAME` must match the value of `pm.status_path` in your PHP-FPM configuration.

The value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is unimportant, but **it must be set**. Omitting this parameter will give you an empty response.

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add this line into the location:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```